# Asyncio Aiohttp Post request Error: Unclosed client session

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am getting this error while sending a list of requests. I have found many other Q&As in stackoverflow with similar problems, but all answers say to use the ClientSession context. Which is exactly what I am doing here, but I still get this error:

```
ERROR - Unclosed client session, client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7f95c1ca37f0>
```

I also tried to explicitly put "await session.close()" at the end, but this error still persists. My code snippet:

```
async def post_request(session, payload):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    headers = {'Authorization':"Bearer " + token,'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    async with session.post(
                url=URL,
                headers=headers,
                data=json.dumps(payload)) as resp:
        print(f'Request sent with status: {resp.status}')
        return resp.status

async def send_many(payload_list):
    tasks = []
    async with ClientSession(raise_for_status=True) as session:
        for payload in payload_list:
            tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(post_request(session=session,payload=payload)))
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

results=asyncio.run(send_many(payload_list))
print(results)
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback message. Also FYI, `ensure_future` has been replaced with `create_task`

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not be the problem but I think you might need to await the response like this:

```
async def post_request(session, payload):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    headers = {'Authorization':"Bearer " + token,'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    async with session.post(
                url=URL,
                headers=headers,
                data=json.dumps(payload)) as resp:
        print(f'Request sent with status: {resp.status}')
        await resp.text() # Or `await resp.json()`
        return resp.status
```